# Need a java way to split XMLS based on tags

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

My requirement id that I am generating an XML in java using Jaxb2Marsheller.
Now, I have to split the xmls based on the tags or XML Element Objects.
For example :
Here is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ed>
    <Template_Name>Template 1</Template_Name>
    <Font_Size>  </Font_Size>
    <RC>RC1</RC>
    <AC>AC1</AC>
    <Date>2015-01-09</Date>
    <Code>A</Code>
    <Mode>B</Mode>
    <Footer_Variables1>
        <RtrnAddr>221||</RtrnAddr>
        <RcptAddr>317</RcptAddr>
    </Footer_Variables1>
    <Footer_Variables2>
        <UserName>Usser1</UserName>
        <CCID>1BCCCCC</CCID>
        <CD>HCP</CD>
        <eName>9_EN</eName>
    </Footer_Variables2>
</ed>
```

I need to split this XML based on any start element, for example
<Footer_Variables1>..</Footer_Variables1>,
<Footer_Variables2>..</Footer_Variables2>,

Comment: Perhaps use a [DOM Parser](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm).

Comment: DOM Parser is surely a choice, however I am looking for any logic that would be a bit less complicated, as my xml is quiet large

Comment: DOM is a lot simpler than coding proper XML handling yourself. The only drawback is that it requires to parse the whole document into RAM. If your document is rather large, consider using the SAX parser. It generates events (like start tag found, end tag found, text found, ...) so you can construct whatever you need based on that.